# How can I receive and use voice commands for AVPlayer? (tvOS, swift)

Tags: swift, avplayer, tvos, avplayerlayer

I have a tvOS app and it has a screen to play videos.
I created this screen using `UIViewController` instead of `AVPlayerViewController` and use `AVPlayerLayer` to play videos.

Now, I'd like to utilize voice commands of Siri remotes such as "fast forward" or "What did they say?" when playing videos.

I googled and googled but never found how I can do this.

Can I use voice command without `AVPlayerViewController`?
If so, how?

Here are some links I googled to deal with this problem.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avkit/avplayerviewcontroller
https://github.com/Lax/iOS-Swift-Demos/tree/master/MPRemoteCommandSample

So far, I've thought `MPRemoteCommandCenter` or `UIGestureRecognizer` or `SiriKit` might help...

Answer (score 0):

I use `MPRemoteCommandCenter` and could utilize voice commands of Siri.

Sample source is here. 
https://github.com/Lax/iOS-Swift-Demos/tree/master/MPRemoteCommandSample